# Three.js 3D model disappears after applying texture

Tags: javascript, three.js, texture-mapping

I've successfully imported a 3D model via a obj file. It displays on the screen fine. But when I try to apply the texture the model disappears. Any ideas why?

```
var texture = new THREE.Texture();
var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader( manager );
            loader.load( './models/Leather-Black.jpg', function ( image ) {

                texture.image = image;
            } );

loader.load( './models/Sofa000.obj', function ( object ) {

object.traverse( function( node ) { if ( node instanceof THREE.Mesh ) { 
                    node.castShadow = true;
                    node.material.map = texture;
                    } 
                    });
                    object.scale.set(30,20,30);
                    object.rotation.y = Math.PI/180 * 180;
                    scene.add( object );
                });
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Did you check the downloaded image in the network panel of the developer console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loader.load()` is asynchronous. so your `texture` variable is `undefined` when you assign to the `material.map`. What you need to is use the callback function of the `TextureLoader()` so that you would know that the image has loaded and then apply it to the material.